# JVM heap dump without trace information: "Unresolved Name"

Tags: java, heap-dump, jmc, hprof, eclipse-memory-analyzer

There is a memory issue on our production environment.
We're running under OpenJDK 14.0.1+7 with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
I've loaded created hprof file into Eclipse Memory Analyzer it shows some problems but without class names information in the report, just shows "Unresolved Name"
[image]
[image]

I've tried to analyze dump with Java Mission Control but it also shows
report without class names.

Both JMC and Eclipse MAT was running with the same version of java 14.0.1+7 under which the dump was created.

I've not found any info about this problem on the internet just one link [here](https://www.jeroenreijn.com/2020/12/heapdump-unresolved-name.html). I've tried to use different JVMs for MAT and JMC but without success.
It looks very strange.

Does anybody know is this problem related with the created dump?
How can I avoid this and see the real class names?

Comment: Eclipse Memory Analyzer didn't find the class name in constant pool (in the HPROF file) from the address.
Perhaps OpenJDK 14.0.1+7 has generated a corrupt HPROF file or generates it in a slightly different format or the file was corrupted when it was transferred. Do any other tools e.g. VisualVM read the HPROF file correctly? Does it work with different HPROF files?

Why are you still running OpenJDK 14.0.1+7 in production? You won't have had any security fixes for at least two years.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, it seems that in some cases 14.0.1 creates corrupted hprof file, because yesterday was failure again on OOM and created hprof file was successfully loaded in MAT with class names.